# Finding the symmetries of Coronene (24 carbon atoms and 12 hydrogen)

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, permutations, polya-counting-theory

My question is this:

> Coronene consists of 24 carbon atoms and 12 hydrogen atoms arranged as illustrated in the link below. If we allow some or all of the hydrogen atoms to be replaced by chlorine, how many different isomers can be formed? To answer this, let S be the set of the 12 carbon atoms which have a non-carbon attachment. Identify all symmetries of this figure, free to move in 3 dimensions, as permutations of S. Write the pattern inventory for all 2-colorings of S, and determine the total number of 2-colorings.

[This is Coronene.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccz6O.png)

But I can't figure out where to begin finding the symmetries on this thing. Do we go through the edges and the vertices? It seems that going through each vertex goes through the vertex on the opposite side. I'd really appreciate some help finding these symmetries; once I find those, I think that I could easily find the permutations of them, the cycle index, pattern inventory, number of 2-colorings, etc.

Comment: It has the same symmetries as a hexagon no? Six rotations and six reflections.

Comment: Does it? I guess I just assumed it had many more, since it's basically a bunch of mini hexagons.

Comment: Sure, but it has to permute those mini-hexagons amongst themselves and keep the middle one where it is no? It's not like a symmetry can break it apart. The only types of symmetries in this situation are rotations and reflections, so you just have to ask yourself across which lines can you reflect, and by how much you can rotate.

Comment: I think I understand -- so instead of concentrating on the 12 outside vertices, I should just concentrate on the middle hexagon that has 6?

Comment: @anon Also, does that mean that my permutations are going to be in the form of six numbers instead of 12? Just want to be sure.